# NSStream in swift - Xcode 6 Beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, nsstream

I have a output stream in swift to send to another software. It was working in beta 5. When I updated, it stopped working. When I build the app, I get an error related to bridging Objective-C. (Even though I'm using swift) Could it be something with the code? Or is it a problem with xCode. Any help is appreciated. Heres a snippet.

```
var outputStream: NSOutputStream!

    func initNetworkCommunication(){

    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    var hostName:CFString = "localhost"
    var portNumber:UInt32 = 80

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,hostName,portNumber,&readStream,&writeStream)

    self.outputStream! = writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue()

    self.outputStream!.delegate = self

    self.outputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    self.outputStream!.open()

}
```

Also, The problem lies in the scheduleInRunLoop. If I remove that line, it runs. But the stream doesn't function.

Comment: There is not enough information here. Is `self.outputStream` a `NSOutputStream`? Then it works for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: @user3928263 Yes, in the code I also had `var outputStream: NSOutputStream!`. The error I get is very strange. It seems like a system error.
**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TFSs26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveCU__FTPSs9AnyObject_MQ__Q_", referenced from:
      __TFC3New14ViewController24initNetworkCommunicationfS0_FT_T_ in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: Used the wrong username to notify you. Sorry about that. @jtbandes

Comment: I was seeing weird errors that looked like that when I first ran beta6. It eventually went away after I cleared my DerivedData folder and quit/restarted xcode. I also had some trouble running the simulator that just went away after I quit and restarted the simulator a few times.

Comment: Hi, JoeBayLD, This question looks like it does not have an answer. Could you post and accept a quick answer that shows what worked for you? I can see it in the comments but it will be better if you elevate the answer or delete the question. As you know unanswered questions are just clutter and confusing.